# How do you change what can be added to an integer in python?

Tags: python, class, addition

I've been trying to use classes in python to make a new variable type a Quaternion Number.
I've figured out how to make it add an integer or a float to it, but I can't figure out how to make it add a Quaternion to a float/integer. I've only been coding for about a month trying to learn how to program to make a "Universal Calculator For Different Number Systems" or UCFDNS. I'm also trying to make it work for __sub__, __mul__, __div__. Is it even possible?

```
class Quaternion:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.real = a
        self.imag1 = b
        self.imag2 = c
        self.imag3 = d

        #addition

    def __add__(self, other):
        if type(other) == int or type(other) == float:
            other1 = Quaternion(other,0,0,0)
            return other1 + self
        elif type(other)==type(self):
            return Quaternion(other.real+self.real,other.imag1+self.imag1,other.imag2+self.imag2,other.imag3+self.imag3)
        else:
            print('You can'+"'"+'t add a',type(other),' with a QuaternionNumber')
            import sys
            sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're rolling your own? Python has a built-in complex type.

Comment: @blorgon it does? how do I use it?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#complex

Comment: @blorgon does it have stuff for quaternions or other number systems?

Comment: How can I improve my question?

Comment: Not built-in, no. I suggest checking the documentation. A quick google search returned a few hits on quaternion packages for Python, but you could certainly roll your own.

Comment: As a more general note, `sys.exit(1)` is never a good approach to error handling in a library. In this particular case (as per my answer), you should be returning `NotImplemented`. But in general, if you can't handle something, you should be raising an exception, not force-quitting. The former can be handled by the caller and, even if not handled, provides a stack trace and error message for much better debugging use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct implementation of `__add__` should return the special constant `NotImplemented` if it doesn't know how to handle the addition. All Python built-in classes are written to comply with this. If `__add__` returns `NotImplemented` then Python will call `__radd__` on the right-hand side. So all you need to do is implement `__radd__` to do basically the same thing as `__add__` and your class will magically start working with built-in types.

Note that, in order to be respectful of other people doing the same thing, you should also return `NotImplemented` if you can't handle the operation, so your `__add__` (and `__radd__`) should look like

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if type(other) == int or type(other) == float:
        other1 = Quaternion(other,0,0,0)
        return other1 + self
    elif type(other)==type(self):
        return ComplexNumber(other.real+self.real,other.imag1+self.imag1,other.imag2+self.imag2,other.imag3+self.imag3)
    else:
        return NotImplemented
```

Also keep in mind that `__add__` and `__radd__` will look the same, since addition is commutative. But `__sub__` and `__rsub__`, for instance, will look different, because in `__rsub__`, `self` is the *right-hand* side of the subtraction operation and order matters.